# Table pagination bugs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ejs

So recently, I tried to update my pagination code so that i can use it for multiple tables in different pages. But when I added the function based on the table's unique id, first 2 buttons works together and the last 2 works just fine. Additionally, the pagination buttons are inside the same div, which i just can't figure it out why.

This is the function

```
   function setPage(pagination, pageBody){
    $(pagination).after('<div id="nav"> </div>');
    var rowsShown = 4;
    var rowsTotal = $(pageBody).length;
    var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
    for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        $('#nav').append('<button type="button" rel="'+i+'" class="navpage">'+pageNum+'</button> ');
    }
    $(pageBody).hide();
    $(pageBody).slice(0, rowsShown).show();
    $('#nav button:first').addClass('active');
    $('#nav button').bind('click', function(){

        $('#nav button').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
        var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
        var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
        $(pageBody).css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
        css('display','table-row').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
    });
}


setPage('#pagination', '#pagination tbody tr')
setPage('#pagination2', '#pagination2 tbody tr')
```

This is the css code

```
    .navpage {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #3cd45d;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navpage:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

And this is the EJS code

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>Performance</h1>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="button button1" id="addperformance" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal">Add</button>
      <button type="button" class="button button1" id="editperformance" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal1">Edit</button>
      <form action="" class="search-form">
        <input type="search" id="search_p" class="search-input" />
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br />

    <table class="table table-sortable" id="pagination">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Written By</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table_body_p">
        <% for(var i=0; i < data.employeeProfile.length; i++) { %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].name %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].category %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].description %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].date %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeProfile[i].writtenBy %>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <% } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>Personal Information</h1>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="button button1" id="addinfo" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal2">Add</button>
      <button type="button" class="button button1" id="editinfo" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal3">Edit</button>
      <form action="" class="search-form">
        <input type="search" id="search_pi" class="search-input" />
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br />

    <table class="table table-sortable" id="pagination2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Emergency Contact</th>
          <th>Joined Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table_body_pi">
        <% for(var i=0; i < data.employeeResponse.length; i++) { %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].name %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].contact %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].email %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].emergencyContact %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= data.employeeResponse[i].joinedDate %>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <% } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/addNewPerformance') %>
  <%- include('partials/editNewPerformance') %>
    <%- include('partials/addNewInfo') %>
      <%- include('partials/editInfo') %>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*the pagination buttons are inside the same div, which i just can't
> figure it out why.*" -

This is because your code puts them there in a loop. This is happening because you are reusing the `id` attribute of `nav`. So the second time the loop fires it places them inside the first div.

Change the value of the `id` attribute for each call to `setPage()`

UPDATE: OP asked how to create unique ids:

There are many ways to create unique id attributes. But, following the pattern that you've already created, why not use your current method of the id attribute of the table? Namely, pass in a third parameter that is the id of the button div. Like so:

```
setPage('#pagination', '#pagination tbody tr', '#nav')
setPage('#pagination2', '#pagination2 tbody tr', '#nav2')
```

Then within `setPage()` do this:

```
function setPage(pagination, pageBody, buttonDiv){
    $(pagination).after('<div id="'+ buttonDiv +'"> </div>');
      // other code here ...

      // in the for loop
        $(buttonDiv).append('<button type="button" rel="'+i+'" class="navpage">'+pageNum+'</button> ');

     // rest of code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask, if this is the correct implementation of the code for

```
'#nav button:first'
```

to

```
 $(buttonDiv +  'button:first').addClass('active');
    $(buttonDiv + 'button').bind('click', function(){

        $(buttonDiv + 'button').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
```

If this is correct, the pagination buttons are not showing after the code.

Comment: No, isn't correct `$(buttonDiv +  'button:first')` would give you `#navbutton:first` instead of `#nav button:first` - add the space.